# На сервер не загружается файл формата .xlsm

Tags: php, html, apache, fileupload

Сервер Apache.
Создал страницу с формой для загрузки, папку для файлов в.
Грузятся все типы файлов кроме .xlsm
При попытке загрузки данного формата ничего не происходит. Страница просто перезагружается и все. Ошибок не выдает(само отображение ошибок включено)
Я пробовал изменить параметры загружаемых файлов в php.ini . Ничего не поменялось.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Смотрите серверные логи и ответ в [$_FILES](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Файл был бОльшего размера, чем было прописано в файле php.ini . Чтобы найти ошибку при отправке файла просмотрел логи ошибок Apache в файле error.log.
Сама ошибка:
POST Content-Length of 12175407 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

Довольно странно, так как изначально при смене размера загружаемого файла и перезагрузки сервера ничего не происходило. Поставил 60M и заработало.